# updating button text on function return from other class

Tags: java, android, button, return-value

I have a class for a custom dialog showing list items. In another class I create an object and call its methods. In the second class I want a value of the selected list item so I return the value from the first class and update button text to selected item. But I get `null` in return for the first time.

```
 public void onCatButtonClicked(Context context) {
     CatDialog catDialog = new CatDialog(context);
     selectedCat = catDialog.getSelectedCat(context);
     Button.setText(selectedCat.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: What about the code from the second class. It will be helpful to see how it works too.

Comment: What are you passing for your context parameter ?

Comment: @TylerAndFriends getActivity() as context.
the button is updating when click on the second time (with the previous selected item even before selecting the item) but not on the current selection

Comment: your question is very confusing. From what i understand you have a custom dialog class "B" with a listview. you call this class "B" from a class "A" and want to return the selected listview to class "A" ? Is that so?

Comment: AS you @RohanKandwal, I am not getting the point of what is really the question.

Comment: @RohanKandwal yes you got it right. I am setting a member selectedCat in a method in class b on list select item and then have a getter method for that member which returns the value of the member. and as you can see in the above code, selectedCat member of Class A is set to that value.

Comment: You are making the code very confusing. why are you using two classes? and as far as your problem is concerned i think it is due to multiple object creation. if possible don't make separate classes, else try to make classes objects global and static so that their won't be multiple classes. Also please post the some code of the classes since it is unclear from this.